What is the term for look that asks for thinking? And the question that incites thinking?
Imagine this scenario. Two people are having a conversation in which one is trying to explain something to the other. During the course of conversation, the exponent asks the other person a question whose answer will finally connect all the dots for that person.
Is there a term for such a question or this technique of explaining things?
Furthermore, how do I describe the expression of the exponent as he patiently (or without patience) waits for the other person to connect the dots? (Ideally I would like to describe it in as few words as possible.)

Idk but Paul Ekman is the world expert on facial expressions. https://www.paulekman.com/

Like the Socratic method? Is there a special question they include in the conversation, or is it just some random point where the other person starts to get it?

Duh . . . the shortest maybe

I think "quizzical" is the word for the facial expression.

The final question could be called the "prompt".

leading question?

Should I just go with 'he asked with a knowing look'

I suggest this belongs not to English Language & Usage but rather somewhere to do with literature or writing…
